# I need to sort a list of bullets (and sub bullets) in alphabetical order

Tags: microsoft-word, sorting

I have an issue with word's alphabetical sorting. Here is an example of what's going on:

- Question 1

  - Answer 1
- Question 2

  - Answer 2

---

When I press *sort*, this happens:

- Question 1
- Question 2

  - Answer 1
  - Answer 2

---

Any resolution's would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are your settings for styles? What happens in what order? Your question lacks detail. Please add more information as to how the problem arises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Word only supports sorting on single-level lists, so any indents will be treated as a part of that sort operation (which is why the list gets messed up like this).

A work-around for this is to utilize `Outline` mode and set the specific paragraph outline levels of the top level lists and then sort.

First, select all level 1 indents (you can use `CTRL` and double click the word to select it), then right click and select the `Paragraph` menu option to bring up the paragraph options. In here make sure the `Indents and Spacing` tab is selected and change the `Outline level` option from `Body Text` to `Level 1`.

[image: Paragraph Menu]

Next, click the `View` tab in the ribbon menu and select `Outline`, this will give you a sort of "table of contents" type of view for your document; on this tab there's a drop down list labeled `Show Level:` which should say `All Levels`, change this to `Level 1` and now only the top level indents will be displayed (i.e. "Question X") with the sub-level indents collapsed.

[image: Show Level X]

Now you can sort: click the `Home` tab in the ribbon menu, click the `Sort` button and the top level indents will be sorted accordingly. After the values are sorted, you can leave `Outline` mode.

The one caveat to this is the time (having to select each top-level indent), as well, you'll need to make sure that each time you add a top-level bullet, you must set it's `Outline level` to `1` (or set a default style to do this automatically).

Hope that can help!

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix (that will limit your formatting options) is to keep the answers in the same paragraph as the question.  To create a line break between the question and answer, enter a line break <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> rather than a standard paragraph break <kbd>enter</kbd>.  This will allow Word to sort the questions by paragraph and the answer will automatically follow.